# Specify target table for update in FROM clause MySql 8

Tags: mysql, subquery

On MySQL database I have two tables

`tmp1`

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `tmp1`;
+-----+---------------------+-----------+----------------+--------+
| sID | sDate_sHour         | sName     | sStatus        | sValue |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+----------------+--------+
|   1 | 2019-04-27 14:00:52 | user76681 | not registered | NULL   |
|   2 | 2019-05-08 09:39:19 | user76681 | not registered | NULL   |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+----------------+--------+
2 rows in set
```

And `tmp2`

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `tmp2`;
+-----+---------------------+-----------+------------+
| sID | sDate_sHour         | sName     | sStatus    |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+------------+
|   1 | 2019-05-08 09:36:14 | user76681 | registered |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set
```

When I've on `tmp2` for the same `sName` the `sDate_sHour` higher than the `sDate_sHour` of `tmp1` I need update the column `sValue` with `N` value

return `tmp1` after update

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `tmp1`;
+-----+---------------------+-----------+----------------+--------+
| sID | sDate_sHour         | sName     | sStatus        | sValue |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+----------------+--------+
|   1 | 2019-04-27 14:00:52 | user76681 | not registered | N      |
|   2 | 2019-05-08 09:39:19 | user76681 | not registered | NULL   |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+----------------+--------+
2 rows in set
```

because the date `2019-05-08 09:36:14` from `tmp2` is higher of `2019-04-27 14:00:52` from `tmp1` 
and the date `2019-05-08 09:36:14` from `tmp2` is less of `2019-05-08 09:39:19` from `tmp1`

I've tried using MySQL 8.0.17

I get a compile error when attempting to run the following MYSQL update statement

```
mysql> UPDATE tmp1 AS b
INNER JOIN tmp2 g ON b.sName = g.sName
SET b.sValue = 'N'
WHERE
    g.sDate_sHour > (
        SELECT
            MAX(b.sDate_sHour)
        FROM
            `tmp1` t2
        WHERE
            t2.sName = b.sName
        ORDER BY
            t2.sID DESC
    )
AND b.sStatus IN ('not registered')
AND b.sName = g.sName
ORDER BY
    g.sDate_sHour DESC;
1093 - You can't specify target table 'b' for update in FROM clause
mysql>
```

I have no idea what the problem is.

Please, can you help me ?

Structure tables `tmp1` and `tmp2` below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp1`;
CREATE TABLE `tmp1` (
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sDate_sHour` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sName` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sValue` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tmp1
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tmp1` VALUES ('1', '2019-04-27 14:00:52', 'user76681', 'not registered', null);
INSERT INTO `tmp1` VALUES ('2', '2019-05-08 09:39:19', 'user76681', 'not registered', null);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp2`;
CREATE TABLE `tmp2` (
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sDate_sHour` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sName` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tmp2
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tmp2` VALUES ('1', '2019-05-08 09:36:14', 'user76681', 'registered');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can not use an ORDER BY in a Update query

For your error code simply use a subquery

```
UPDATE tmp1 AS b
INNER JOIN tmp2 g ON b.sName = g.sName
SET b.sValue = 'N'
WHERE
    g.sDate_sHour > (
        SELECT
            MAX(b.sDate_sHour)
        FROM
            (SELECT * FROM  `tmp1`) t2
        WHERE
            t2.sName = b.sName
        ORDER BY
            t2.sID DESC
    )
AND b.sStatus IN ('not registered')
AND b.sName = g.sName
;
```